# 10 year ban on uk visa, can I apply for a different visa type?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, uk-citizens

If a person has a 10 year ban on student visa entry and 10 years hasn't passed yet, is there any chance to reapply with another visa category? I was banned for 10 years in 2010.

Comment: As others have said below, no. You're 9/10 years through, any legal action or claims would be hugely expensive, and likely wouldn't reach a conclusion soon anyway. Your best bet is to wait it out for the final year, and then apply again and see if you are accepted. Spend this time making sure your next application is strong.

Comment: If you’ve built up a good travel history and credible ties to your country of residence since your ban, wait it out and reapply when the ban is over, making sure that you have good evidence showing you meet the visa criteria and that whatever caused your ban won’t be repeated. If you reapply, you might want to get an Immigration lawyer with experience of applications to the UK to look over your submission. 10 year bans are only given after removal/deportation or for using deception in an application for entry clearance; adding a refusal to that history would not be a good thing.

Comment: What other visa category did you have in mind?

Answer (score 7):

An entry ban means *you* are banned for 10 years, no matter what name, passport, or visa you attempt to use.

If you received a ban in 2010, then you only have a year or so to wait until the ban expires. Then you may apply for a visa, but there is no guarantee it will be approved.

Comment: Apparently some bans do not apply to family visa applications, so the first sentence isn't entirely true.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gregs answer, the only way to circumvent a ban for the UK is to either:

1. challenge it on human rights grounds - this is massively expensive and nowhere near guaranteed to get you anywhere, even if you have a strong case.
2. Become an EU citizen and leverage the freedom of movement, as this supersedes any bans in place - note, this is only *guaranteed* to be viable for the next week or so, so move quickly...

Comment: Are you saying there are no grounds on which an EU citizen can be refused entry to the UK? Including having committed a serious crime, or being deemed ‘not conducive to public good’?

Comment: @Traveller Past convictions are not, in themselves, grounds for denial of entry. However, if the person is judged to be a "genuine, present and sufficiently serious threat affecting one of the fundamental interests of society" (criminality, public health etc) they can be.

Comment: It has to be said that UK immigration takes a very, very dim view of people who attempt to challenge refusals on human rights grounds without an extremely good reason. A spurious challenge will damage your future chances of a visa.

Comment: -1 @Traveller, Moo A EU citizen can be deported and banned from another EU country, but the threshold is high. In the context of this answer, the statement is very unrealistic.

Answer (score -1):

As far i know they will not issue you with visa for under the same category but after your ten ban. your are likely to get the visa if you provide all the information. please remember to state all refusals and on your application form. Be honest